# If statement to ensure string does not exist in a number of files

Tags: bash, grep

I've been having an absolute brutal of at time doing something that should be fairly simple.

I've tried everything I can think of over the last few hours, but I just can't get it to work. Most recent attempt is here

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
if [[ $(grep -q 10.212.5.5 /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) == 0 ]] && [[ $(grep -q 10.212.5.15} /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) == 0  ]] && [[ $(grep -q 10.212.5.5 file1) == 0 ]] && [[ $(grep -q 10.212.5.5 file2) == 0 ]] ; then echo "notfound" ; fi
```

Comment: Should it be the same string every time?

Comment: `$()` returns the contents of the command -- not the exit code of the `grep` as you may have hoped.  I would turn this into a `for` loop to avoid so much repeated typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands (e.g. `grep`) generally return two different kinds of results: output (what they print during operation) and an exit status (best thought of as success vs. failure). As chicks pointed, shell's `$(somecommand)` construct captures the output of the command, *not* its exit status; but `grep`'s `-q` option prevents it from producing output, so `$( )` winds up capturing *nothing*.

I see two easy ways to fix this (provided I understand what you're trying to do). The first is to use `grep -c` instead of `-q`, so it outputs the number of matches found, and you can capture that with `$( )` and compare to 0, exactly as you're doing (although I wrapped the lines for readability):

```
if [[ $(grep -c 10.212.5.5 /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) == 0 ]] &&
   [[ $(grep -c 10.212.5.15 /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) == 0  ]] &&
   [[ $(grep -c 10.212.5.5 file1) == 0 ]] &&
   [[ $(grep -c 10.212.5.5 file2) == 0 ]] ; then
       echo "notfound"
fi
```

The other option is to use `grep -q`, but look at its exit status. Checking the exit status of a command in `if` is trivial - just use the command itself as the test condition. But in this case it's backward, since `grep` returns success if the pattern was found, and failure if it wasn't; you want the test to succeed if it *wasn't* found, so use `!` to reverse the status:

```
if ! grep -q 10.212.5.5 /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf &&
   ! grep -q 10.212.5.15 /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf &&
   ! grep -q 10.212.5.5 file1 &&
   ! grep -q 10.212.5.5 file2 ; then
       echo "notfound"
fi
```